# Visual Studio Code on mac using python Error "syntax error: invalid syntax" at the line 'cerebro = bt.Cerebro()'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, backtrader

I'm using VSCode with python to do some backtesting using backtrader. I just starting following a tutorial and the first test code seems to comeup with a syntax error when instantiating cerebro. Here is the code:

```
import backtrader as bt
from datetime import datetime

class LogClass(bt.Strategy):
  def __init__(self):
    self.dataclose = self.datas[0].close

  def log(next, txt, dt=None):
    dt = dt or self.datas[0].datetime.date(0)
    print(f'{dt} {txt}')

  def next(self):
    self.log('Close: {}'.format(self.dataclose[0])

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(dataname=LogClose.params.ticker,
                             fromdate= LogClose.params.fromDate,
                             todate= LogClose.params.toDate)

cerebro.adddata(data)

cerebro.addstrategy(LogClose)

cerebro.run()
```

when I run the file using 'Run Python File in Terminal', I get the error

```
File "log.py", line 16
cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried searching for a solution with no luck.
I changed the interpreter to use python3.7, installed pylint, update pip. restarted the laptop, nothing. Help.

Comment: Main Menu → View → Render Whitespace

Comment: As usual, the problem is an unclosed parenthesis on the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in def next() self.log() unmatched (
add a ) to the end of self.log('Close: {}'.format(self.dataclose[0])

Comment: Thank you all very much. I cannot beleive I spent 2 days searching the web and wasting your time for such simple overlooked error. I'm just surprised VSCode didn't provide me with a better error description. Thank you very much.

Comment: that happens sometimes... try looking above and below (usually above) where the ide thinks the error is at